# What does ^{} mean in C?

Tags: c, objective-c-blocks, llvm-clang

I came across the following code snippet:

```
void solve_symbols() {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    getClass = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "objc_getClass");
    getClassObj = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "object_getClass");
    registerName = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "sel_registerName");
    respondsToSelector = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "class_respondsToSelector");
    msgSend = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "objc_msgSend");
  });
}
```

Code can be found here: [GitHub:ParasiteLoader/loader.c](https://github.com/ParasiteTeam/loader/blob/master/ParasiteLoader/loader.c)

What does `^{ getClass = dlsy... }` do/mean?

Comment: it is called Block https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Comment: @KeithNicholas I believe Block is a C extension `A new derived type is introduced to C and, by extension, Objective-C, C++, and Objective-C++` http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html

Comment: To people that jumped to edit this with irrelevant titles and tags, please take a look at the OP's link before doing so. Thanks.

Comment: I thought it is Microsoft's responsibility to add new syntax and non-standard extensions into existing programming languages (C++/CLI, checked C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called block and it is language-level addition to C and Obj-C. It is a function that treated like an object. Those, it is implementation of [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) concept in C. Adds more functional programming flavour.

You can find syntax and usage practice recommendations in this [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)